# Threadsafe Control access failing. Causes control to vanish

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, controls, thread-safety

C# VS 2015 CE

I created a System Tray App that uses a form for a Settings Dialog.  The same form has a multiline textbox used for logging messages.

Timer callbacks on the main thread append messages to the textbox log.

Here is the thread safe code from the Settings Form:

```
delegate void SetTextCallBack(string message);

private void SetLogText(string text)
{
    if (textBoxLog.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallBack d = new SetTextCallBack(SetLogText);
        textBoxLog.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
    }
    else
    {
        if (!textBoxLog.Text.Equals("")) textBoxLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        textBoxLog.AppendText(text);
    }
}
```

Now if I have the settings form open the main thread displays its messages whenever a timer callback occurs.

If the setting form is closed it correctly displays the first message but any subsequent message causes the textbox control to vanish (discovered when it is reopened).

[image]

There are no errors generated so the textbox must be there somewhere but it seems to have lost it's connection to the form.

Any clues welcome!

Adding the events has caused the behaviour to change slighly.  All messages are now recorded until the first time the settings form dialog is closed.

Here follows an event list:

```
Textbox Log Visibly Changed         ' App First Started and first message written by MAIN() Form instaniated but not displayed
SetTextCallback: Appending Text
Textbox Log Visibly Changed
Textbox Log Text Changed
Timer Entered                   ' First timer event. 2 Messages written
SetTextCallback: Invoking
SetTextCallback: Appending Text
Textbox Log Text Changed
Textbox Log Text Changed
SetTextCallback: Invoking
SetTextCallback: Appending Text
Textbox Log Text Changed
Textbox Log Text Changed
Callback in 60 seconds
Timer Entered                   ' Second timer event. 2 Messages written
SetTextCallback: Invoking
SetTextCallback: Appending Text
Textbox Log Text Changed
Textbox Log Text Changed
SetTextCallback: Invoking
SetTextCallback: Appending Text
Textbox Log Text Changed
Textbox Log Text Changed
Callback in 60 seconds
Timer Entered                   ' Third timer event. 2 Messages written
SetTextCallback: Invoking
SetTextCallback: Appending Text
Textbox Log Text Changed
Textbox Log Text Changed
SetTextCallback: Invoking
SetTextCallback: Appending Text
Textbox Log Text Changed
Textbox Log Text Changed
Callback in 60 seconds
Textbox Log Visibly Changed         ' Settings Form entered by user (ShowDialog) all 7 messages visible
Timer Entered                   ' Forth timer event. 2 Messages written Setting form still open. New messages seen appended.
SetTextCallback: Invoking
SetTextCallback: Appending Text
Textbox Log Text Changed
Textbox Log Text Changed
SetTextCallback: Invoking
SetTextCallback: Appending Text
Textbox Log Text Changed
Textbox Log Text Changed
Callback in 60 seconds
Timer Entered                   ' Fifth timer event. 2 Messages written. Setting form still open. New messages seen appended.
SetTextCallback: Invoking
SetTextCallback: Appending Text
Textbox Log Text Changed
Textbox Log Text Changed
SetTextCallback: Invoking
SetTextCallback: Appending Text
Textbox Log Text Changed
Textbox Log Text Changed
Callback in 60 seconds              ' Return from setting form dialog
Timer Entered                   ' Sixth timer event. 2 Messages written
SetTextCallback: Appending Text         ' The safe thread method is no longer calling the Invoke
Textbox Log Visibly Changed         ' Re-enter setting form.  log textbox is now missing.
Textbox Log Text Changed
Textbox Log Text Changed
SetTextCallback: Appending Text
Textbox Log Text Changed
Textbox Log Text Changed
Callback in 60 seconds              ' Return from setting form dialog again
Textbox Log Visibly Changed
Timer Entered                   ' Seventh timer event. 2 Messages written
SetTextCallback: Invoking           ' Invoke is re-occuring but callback is never fired
SetTextCallback: Invoking           ' Invoke is re-occuring but callback is never fired
Callback in 60 seconds
The program '[0x1458] SystemTrayApp.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: To be clear, messages appear correctly as long as the form is open, correct? If you close and re-open the form, the `TextBox` is displayed correctly if there is only one message but it is not visible if there are multiple messages, correct? Is the same instance of the form displayed each time or is it a new instance each time? Have you tried handling the `VisibleChanged` event of that `TextBox` and placing a breakpoint on it to see if it's hit and when?

Comment: Is the form hidden or actually closed when the log updates? I have a feeling you are doing something while the form is closed. How is the `SetText` called?

Comment: The first message is written by the main thread and not by the timer callback thread.  I suspect this is the difference.  I can have the form open and allow several messages to display but once closed the first message to be written causes the issue.  Trying your suggestion now!

Comment: Ok. The VisibleChanged & TextChanged events both fire several times before stopping altogether.  If I enter the form the VisibleChanged event fires once again. Breaking at that point shows the textbox has no text but shows it's parent is still the settings form and it believes it is still visible.

Comment: I am using ShowDialog to open the form. I assumed when it closed it was just hidden because I can access all the form control values.  If this is not the case then this was my intention!

Comment: Link to VS 2015 Project : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ot_MBaoCvPtDX9LtV2spg9RNQnZyYQ5X/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have an inelegant solution. After returning from the SettingForm.ShowDialog() I record all the Form Control values including the Log textbox.  I then dispose the SettingForm and instantiate a new one and reset all the Control values to the recorded values.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem turns out to be...

The Handle for the Dialog Window is released upon return from the dialog.

The solution is to re-create the handle after the ShowDialog!!!

Like so:

```
DialogResult diagRes = ShowDialog();
if (!IsHandleCreated) CreateHandle();
```

Problem fixed!